# Two Groups with the same sAMAccountName, using FindOne() to getting the second occurance of group

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I have a user that i'm currently listing "memberOf". I wanted to get some details about each group the user is a member of, such as distinguishedName, last modified, and description... The problem is, I'm using FindOne() in my code and i have a couple groups with sAMAccountName that are duplicated in various domains. Is there a way to use FindOne() and get the second occurance of the group as I have it coded below, or do I need to rewrite and use FindAll() and handling it that way. 
Relevant Code Below:

```
foreach (object item in groups)
            {
                string groupProp = string.Empty;
                using (DirectoryEntry dirEntry = CreateDirectoryEntry())
                {
                    using (DirectorySearcher dirSearcher2 = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry))
                    {
                        dirSearcher2.Filter = string.Format("(sAMAccountName=" + item + ")");
                        dirSearcher2.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
                        dirSearcher2.PropertiesToLoad.Add("whenChanged");
                        dirSearcher2.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

                        SearchResult searchResult2 = dirSearcher2.FindOne();

                        if (searchResult2 != null)
                        {
                            DirectoryEntry employee = searchResult2.GetDirectoryEntry();
                            string desc = string.Empty;
                            string date = string.Empty;
                            string dname = string.Empty;
                            if (employee.Properties["description"].Value != null)
                            {
                                desc = employee.Properties["description"].Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (employee.Properties["whenChanged"].Value != null)
                            {
                                date = employee.Properties["whenChanged"].Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (employee.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value != null)
                            {
                                dname = employee.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
                                if (dname.Contains("DC=academic"))
                                {
                                    dname = "academic";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
```

Relevant New Code:

```
using (var results = dirSearcher2.FindAll())
                        {
                            foreach (SearchResult searchResult2 in results)
                            {
                                html.Append("<tr><td>" + item.ToString() + "</td>");
                                if (searchResult2.Properties.Contains("description"))
                                {
                                    desc = searchResult2.Properties["description"][0].ToString();
                                }
                                if (searchResult2.Properties.Contains("whenChanged"))
                                {
                                    date = searchResult2.Properties["whenChanged"][0].ToString();
                                }
                                if (searchResult2.Properties.Contains("distinguishedName"))
                                {
                                    dom = searchResult2.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
                                    if (dom.Contains("DC=academic"))
                                    {
                                        dname = "academic";
                                    }
                                    else if (dom.Contains("DC=office"))
                                    {
                                        dname = "office";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        dname = "not listed";
                                    }
                                }
                                html.Append("<td>" + desc + "</td><td>" + dname + "</td><td>" + date + "</td></tr>");
                            }
```

Essentially, I'm getting the same results as it was getting with my first code, IE not getting the correct information on the second Group. IE: i have two groups named AppDev, both are on different domains; however, both show academic in the display. When I look in AD, i see that the distiguished name shows DC=office on one group, though the code above isn't pulling that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindOne()` only finds one. If you need to see more, you will need to use `FindAll()`. Just make sure you wrap the result in a `using` statement, since the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall) says that you can have memory leaks if you don't:

```
using (var results = dirSearcher2.FindAll()) {
    foreach (SearchResult searchResult2 in results) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

If you only want to find 2 (for example, if you only need to know if more than one exists), then you can set the [`SizeLimit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.sizelimit) property of your `DirectorySearcher` to `2`:

```
dirSearcher2.SizeLimit = 2;
```

A note about efficiency: When you use `.GetDirectoryEntry()` and then get the properties from the `DirectoryEntry` object, `DirectoryEntry` actually goes back out to AD to get those attributes, even though you already got them during your search. You already used `PropertiesToLoad` to ask for those attributes, so they are already available in your `SearchResult` object. Just be aware that all attributes in the `Properties` list of `SearchResult` are presented as arrays, so you always need to use `[0]`, even if they are single-valued attributes in AD.

```
if (searchResult2.Properties.Contains("description")) {
    desc = searchResult2.Properties["description"][0];
}
```

If also need to make sure you are searching the Global Catalog, which will return results from all domains in your forest. You do this by creating the `DirectoryEntry` that you use for your `SearchRoot` with `GC://` instead of `LDAP://`. This tell it to use port 3268 (the GC port) rather than the default LDAP port (389). You are creating this object in your `CreateDirectoryEntry()` method.

Comment: Gabriel, I implemented your solution, which works for the most part; however, I'm still getting repeat data for the groups that share the same name (when i can look at active directory and see they are different). Do I need to increment [0] to get the next array's information.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you update your question and add your new code?

Comment: Hrm... it's not obvious to me why. Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the loop (the `html.Append` line) and step through it (F10) to see what it's doing and the values it's finding.

Comment: Well, FindAll() is pulling back one record, even though 2 exist. It was still duplicating because I had it doubled in the List<t> that stores the intial group listings (pulled by user). The foreach loop is only iterating once.

Comment: So, the only way you can find two accounts with the same username in one search is if: 1. The two accounts are on domains in the same AD forest, and 2. You are searching the global catalog. So are both domains in the same AD forest? And in your `CreateDirectoryEntry()` method, are you creating it with `GC://` to search the global catalog?

Comment: I'm using `LDAP://` and both domains are in the same AD Forest. (I used the same function call to get the user memberOf attribute which list both groups.

Comment: `memberOf` finds both groups because you are reading `memberOf` from a single AD object (you are only talking to one domain). If you want to search all the domains in your forest, you need to change that `LDAP://` to `GC://`.

Comment: More details about the Global Catalog [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/binding-to-the-global-catalog)

Comment: Gabriel, thank you for sticking with me in solving this solution. switching to GC:// gave me what i was looking for, but brought up a few other issues, that I'm confident I can now work out. Best, ~Shane

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.